# Search in CSV and count the entries

Tags: linux, shell, csv, grep, find

I have a csv file which imaging my inventory sort and uniq:

```
|Nivcomp Nivelliergerät
|Bosch Rotationslaser GRL 300 HV
|Renault T440
|Renault Master
|Spritzer Silo
...
```

The second CSV file contains the complete inventory. I would like to find and count the entries of uniq.csv in cominv.csv. So that I become a new csv file with:

```
|Renault T440|20
|Spritzer Silo |10
...
```

I try with while read line, cat and grep but it would not really work.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

file="cominv.csv"
newfile="uniq.csv"

if [[ -f $file ]]; then
    cat $file | uniq > $newfile
fi

if [[ -f $newfile ]]; then
    while read line
    do
        cat $file  | grep $line | wc -l
    done < $newfile
fi
```

Thank you for help
Silvio

Comment: I load on google drive. uniq is like the name say, cominv is the complete inventory. I want count for example all entries in cominv for T440. So like read line in uniq, search entry in cominv and count it and write name and number in new file. (https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B2mNrGo6v2kDS0pzc2lVZUo2bGM?usp=sharing)

Comment: `grep -Ff uniqFile.csv cominv.csv` should work in a Linux environment. `fgrep` in old Unix environments. Good luck.

Comment: display only the list of content.